# ssh port forwarding syntax explanation

Tags: docker, ssh, portforwarding

I am inheriting some devops code, which has some port forwarding calls as follows:

```
server = 180.10.0.1   # fake  IP
ssh ubuntu@' + server + ' -L2222:localhost:2222 -L 27017:some_docker.amazonaws.com:27017'
```

I am really struggling to figure out what is happening here. So, from what I can understand, the traffic on port `2222` or the `server` is being redirected to port `2222` on the local  machine. However, I am not sure what is happening to the port `27017` of the docker image running on the `server`. Is it being redirected to port `27017` of the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port 27017 is forwarded to the mongo/document db host. This is done to enable the mongo driver to talk to the remote database.

Comment: Thank you for that. can you comment on the directionality of the port forwarding? I am really confused about that. Is the port 27017 on the local machine being forwarded to the port on docker client? Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: The port is forwarded from the docker container to the remote mongo host. It is of course both directions so that the driver can talk to mongo and mongo can talk to the driver in the docker. Your local machine can not talk to this port as long as you don't expose the port via -p 27017:27017 when starting the docker.

Answer (score 1):

-Lport:host:hostport

Opens a listening socket on the local machine (where the ssh command has been run on). If a connection is opened, it tunnels it to the remote side and connects to host:hostport. So 2222 is f.e. listening only on localhost on the remote machine. Using this tunnel, you can connect to it via port (2222) from your local machine, even though the socket on the remote machine is only listening on localhost (for example).
The second part is similar, only that host:hostport is a different machine, that is f.e. only accessible from the host that you connected to via SSH:

A --[ssh]-->B--->C

Check the manpages: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

Comment: Thanks, super explanation as well. So, in this case C is only accessible via B and so  one must first tunnel to B to get to C?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just for completeness: you can also do the reverse (-R) which opens a port on the remote side (if allowed) and tunnels the connection to your host which can then f.e. connect to another host that is only accessible from calling side. This can be used to allow the remote host to access some local resource... -L and -R specify, where the listening port is created: on local (-L) or remote (-R) side...